# spotify on Debian: outdated package required

Tags: debian

I recently read these instructions for installing Spotify on Debian 8

https://gist.github.com/ed-flanagan/7068f869a98ea534b8c2

Essentially, the suggestion is to install an outdated version of libgcrypt (i.e. libgcrypt11).

How bad is this idea? Would this affect other applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably harmless.  Many lib packages in debian have (part of) the .so version in the package name.  This usually indicates that multiple packaged versions of the same library can be safely installed at the same time.

When there are exceptions, this is usually handled by `Conflicts:` lines in the .deb package, to prevent both versions being installed at the same time.

e.g. my Debian Sid system currently has the following installed:

```
$ dlocate -l libgcrypt | grep '^ii'
ii  libgcrypt11:amd64   1.5.4-3             amd64 LGPL Crypto library - runtime library
ii  libgcrypt11-dev     1.5.4-3+really1.6.4 all transitional libgcrypt11-dev package
ii  libgcrypt20:amd64   1.6.4-3             amd64 LGPL Crypto library - runtime library
ii  libgcrypt20-dev     1.6.4-3             amd64 LGPL Crypto library - development files
```

Comment: @Reyx_0 This also means that newer programs will continue to use the latest or more recent versions of libcrypt for which they were built.